# Predetermine the number of nested levels before assigning label types

Tags: counters, enumitem

I use the `enumitem` package to set counter types, for example
most of the time I don't need more than 3 levels, and this is my preferred setup:

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)},ref={\arabic*)}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\roman*)},ref={\roman*)}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\alph*)},ref={\alph*)}}
```

Just in case I need a fourth level, I've set

```
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\Alph*)},ref={\Alph*)}}
```

But of course, conditional on needing four levels, It would be much more pleasing to use something like

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)},ref={\arabic*)}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\Roman*)},ref={\Roman*)}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\roman*)},ref={\roman*)}}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\alph*)},ref={\alph*)}}
```

So what I'd like to do is find the maximum number of levels after the first run of pdflatex, and then condition on that number to set the label types.   is there some way of doing this?

Here's an MWE.
For this example I have four levels and want to condition on the existence of this many  active levels, and then switch to \Roman in level 2 and \roman in level 3.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*).},ref={\arabic*)}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\roman*)},ref={\roman*)}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\alph*)},ref={\alph*)}}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\Roman*)},ref={\Roman*)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item level 1
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item  level 2
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item level 3   
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item level 4
            \end{enumerate} 
        \end{enumerate} 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Sure, just use it to the `.aux` file. Could you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), please? This will very much increase your chances that someone will post a complete answer.

Comment: I've added an MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use the `.aux` file, for example like this.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
  \newif\if@enumerate@leveliv@used
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \if@enumerate@leveliv@used
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\Roman*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\roman*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\alph*)}, before*={\global\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue}}
    \else
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\roman*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\alph*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\Alph*)}, before*={\global\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue}}
    \fi
    \@enumerate@leveliv@usedfalse
  }
  \AtEndDocument{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \global
      \if@enumerate@leveliv@used
        \protect\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue
      \else
        \protect\@enumerate@leveliv@usedfalse
      \fi
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item level 1
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item  level 2
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item level 3
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item level 4
      \end{enumerate} 
    \end{enumerate} 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

- As always with the `.aux` file, you have to run LaTeX twice for changes to take effect.
- If you want `ref` to have the same value as `label`, you don't have to set it explicitly.

Comment: Perfect,  thanks very much.