# Predetermine the number of nested levels before assigning label types (followup)

Tags: counters, enumitem

In [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506303/predetermine-the-number-of-nested-levels-before-assigning-label-types), @schtandard taught me how to predetermine whether I had 4 enumerate levels or 3, and condition on this how I supecified my labels.  His/her code worked beautifully so I tried to extend it to check whether I had 2, 3, or 4 levels.    But I wasn't able to do it.     Here's my extension of @schtandard's code.      The example has 3 levels, and if I were coding correctly, the macro \whichLevel would say 3 levels, but it says two levels, so I'm not conditioning properly.   Could somebody point out what I'm doing wrong, please?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
  \newif\if@enumerate@leveliv@used
  \newif\if@enumerate@levelii@used
  \newif\if@enumerate@leveliii@used
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \if@enumerate@leveliv@used
        \def\whichLevel{level 4 is the true condition}
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\Roman*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\roman*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\alph*)}, before*= {\global\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue}}
    \else
        \if@enumerate@leveliii@used
            \def\whichLevel{level 3 is the true condition}
            \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}}
            \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\roman*)}}
            \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\alph*)}, before*= {\global\@enumerate@leveliii@usedtrue}}
        \else
            \def\whichLevel{level 2 is the true condition}
            \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\roman*)}}
            \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*)},before*= {\global\@enumerate@levelii@usedtrue}}
        \fi
    \fi
    \@enumerate@leveliv@usedfalse
    \@enumerate@levelii@usedfalse
    \@enumerate@leveliii@usedfalse
  }
  \AtEndDocument{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \global
        %
        %
       \if@enumerate@leveliv@used
            \protect\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue
       \else
            \protect\@enumerate@leveliv@usedfalse
            \if@enumerate@leveliii@used
                \protect\@enumerate@leveliii@usedtrue
            \else
                \protect\@enumerate@leveliii@usedfalse
                \if@enumerate@levelii@used
                    \protect\@enumerate@levelii@usedtrue
                \else
                    \protect\@enumerate@levelii@usedfalse
                \fi
            \fi
       \fi
    }%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item level 1
       \item \whichLevel
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item   level 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item   level 3
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In case you expected otherwise: @-mentions don't do anything in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You need to set `\global\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue` whenever level 4 is used, regardless of how many levels you expected at the beginning of the document (the same holds for the other levels).
2. You need to set the all switches globally in the `.aux` file.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
  \newif\if@enumerate@leveliv@used
  \newif\if@enumerate@levelii@used
  \newif\if@enumerate@leveliii@used
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \if@enumerate@leveliv@used
      \def\whichLevel{level 4 is the true condition}
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\Roman*)},       before*={\global\@enumerate@levelii@usedtrue}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\roman*)},       before*={\global\@enumerate@leveliii@usedtrue}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\alph*)},        before*={\global\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue}}
    \else
        \if@enumerate@leveliii@used
            \def\whichLevel{level 3 is the true condition}
            \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}}
            \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\roman*)}, before*={\global\@enumerate@levelii@usedtrue}}
            \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\alph*)},  before*={\global\@enumerate@leveliii@usedtrue}}
            \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={XX},       before*={\global\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue}}
        \else
            \def\whichLevel{level 2 is the true condition}
            \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\roman*)}}
            \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*)},  before*={\global\@enumerate@levelii@usedtrue}}
            \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={XX},       before*={\global\@enumerate@leveliii@usedtrue}}
            \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={XX},       before*={\global\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue}}
        \fi
    \fi
    \@enumerate@leveliv@usedfalse
    \@enumerate@levelii@usedfalse
    \@enumerate@leveliii@usedfalse
  }
  \AtEndDocument{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \global
      \if@enumerate@leveliv@used
        \protect\@enumerate@leveliv@usedtrue
      \else
        \protect\@enumerate@leveliv@usedfalse
        \global
        \if@enumerate@leveliii@used
          \protect\@enumerate@leveliii@usedtrue
        \else
          \protect\@enumerate@leveliii@usedfalse
          \global
          \if@enumerate@levelii@used
            \protect\@enumerate@levelii@usedtrue
          \else
            \protect\@enumerate@levelii@usedfalse
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item level 1
  \item \whichLevel
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item level 2
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item level 3
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

However, if you want to store the maximum list depth, it is better to use a counter than a series of switches.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
  \newcounter{enumerate@max@level}
  \def\register@enumerate@level#1{%
    \ifnum\value{enumerate@max@level}<#1\relax
      \setcounter{enumerate@max@level}{#1}%
    \fi
  }
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifcase\numexpr\value{enumerate@max@level}-3\relax
      % 3 levels
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}, before*={\register@enumerate@level{1}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\roman*)},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{2}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\alph*)},   before*={\register@enumerate@level{3}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={XX},        before*={\register@enumerate@level{4}}}
    \or
      % 4 levels
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}, before*={\register@enumerate@level{1}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\Roman*)},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{2}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\roman*)},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{3}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\alph*)},   before*={\register@enumerate@level{4}}}
    \else
      % default
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\roman*)},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{1}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*)},   before*={\register@enumerate@level{2}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={XX},        before*={\register@enumerate@level{3}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={XX},        before*={\register@enumerate@level{4}}}
    \fi
    \edef\enumeratemaxlevel{\theenumerate@max@level}
    \setcounter{enumerate@max@level}{0}%
  }
  \AtEndDocument{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \protect\setcounter{enumerate@max@level}{\theenumerate@max@level}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

There are \enumeratemaxlevel\ enumeration levels in this document.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item level 1
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item level 2
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item level 3
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much