# Predetermine the number of nested levels before assigning label types (Followup #2)

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

In a couple of threads, the second of which was[this one,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508327/predetermine-the-number-of-nested-levels-before-assigning-label-types-followup?noredirect=1#comment1289746_508327), @schtandard taught me how to condition on the number of enumerate levels that I had.     The MWE below illustrates an extremely weird issue with the structure.      The code as written works fine, recognizing that the number of levels I'm using is 3 and behaving accordingly.    But if you comment out the last line, i.e., `word`, it thinks there are only two levels.    Then if you comment out the penultimate line, i.e., `\newpage`, it again works fine.      So there's something about a `\newpage`, which is *not* followed immediately by some text, that messes things up.   (Obviously, the real-world context in which this problem arose was more complex, but this example seems to isolate the problem).    Could somebody please explain what's going on, and how to insulate myself from this problem?

thanks very much for your help!

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno,fleqn]{amsart}%
\usepackage{enumitem}
%This came from this thread
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508327/predetermine-the-number-of-nested-levels-before-assigning-label-types-followup?noredirect=1#comment1289746_508327
\makeatletter
  \newcounter{enumerate@max@level}
  \def\register@enumerate@level#1{%
    \ifnum\value{enumerate@max@level}<#1\relax
      \setcounter{enumerate@max@level}{#1}%
    \fi
  }
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifcase\numexpr\value{enumerate@max@level}-3\relax
      % 3 levels
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)\hspace{1ex}}, before*={\register@enumerate@level{1}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\roman*)\hspace{1ex}},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{2}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\alph*)\hspace{1ex}},   before*={\register@enumerate@level{3}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={XX},        before*={\register@enumerate@level{4}}}
    \or
      % 4 levels
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)\hspace{1ex}}, before*={\register@enumerate@level{1}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\Roman*)\hspace{1ex}},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{2}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\roman*)\hspace{1ex}},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{3}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\alph*)\hspace{1ex}},   before*={\register@enumerate@level{4}}}
    \else
      % default
      \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\roman*)\hspace{1ex}},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{1}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*)\hspace{1ex}},   before*={\register@enumerate@level{2}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={XX},        before*={\register@enumerate@level{3}}}
      \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={XX},        before*={\register@enumerate@level{4}}}
    \fi
    \edef\enumeratemaxlevel{\theenumerate@max@level}
    \setcounter{enumerate@max@level}{0}%
  }
  \AtEndDocument{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \protect\setcounter{enumerate@max@level}{\theenumerate@max@level}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Enumerate 1)
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Enumerate i)
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item  Enumerate a)
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\newpage
word
\end{document}
```

Comment: \item starts a new paragraph, so you at least include a \null before terminating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the value of `\theenumerate@max@level` to the `.aux` immediately, not using `\protected@write`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem}

%This came from this thread
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508327/predetermine-the-number-of-nested-levels-before-assigning-label-types-followup?noredirect=1#comment1289746_508327
\makeatletter
\newcounter{enumerate@max@level}
\def\register@enumerate@level#1{%
  \ifnum\value{enumerate@max@level}<#1\relax
    \setcounter{enumerate@max@level}{#1}%
  \fi
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifcase\numexpr\value{enumerate@max@level}-3\relax
    % 3 levels
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)\hspace{1ex}}, before*={\register@enumerate@level{1}}}
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\roman*)\hspace{1ex}},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{2}}}
    \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\alph*)\hspace{1ex}},   before*={\register@enumerate@level{3}}}
    \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={XX},                    before*={\register@enumerate@level{4}}}
  \or
    % 4 levels
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)\hspace{1ex}}, before*={\register@enumerate@level{1}}}
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\Roman*)\hspace{1ex}},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{2}}}
    \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\roman*)\hspace{1ex}},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{3}}}
    \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\alph*)\hspace{1ex}},   before*={\register@enumerate@level{4}}}
  \else
    % default
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\roman*)\hspace{1ex}},  before*={\register@enumerate@level{1}}}
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*)\hspace{1ex}},   before*={\register@enumerate@level{2}}}
    \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={XX},                    before*={\register@enumerate@level{3}}}
    \setlist[enumerate,4]{label={XX},                    before*={\register@enumerate@level{4}}}
  \fi
  \edef\enumeratemaxlevel{\theenumerate@max@level}
  \setcounter{enumerate@max@level}{0}%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \noexpand\setcounter{enumerate@max@level}{\theenumerate@max@level}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enumerate 1)
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Enumerate i)
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item  Enumerate a)
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\newpage
%word

\end{document}
```

This leaves the following in your `.aux`:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{tocindent-1}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent0}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent1}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent2}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent3}{0pt}
\global \c@enumerate@max@level 3\relax 
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Werner.   It works great, except there's a clash with pdfpages, which i also use.    I didn't want to edit your code, since it fine as it is, but if you add `\usepackage{pdfpages}` either above or below `\usepackage{enumitem}` it will crash.    Could you suggest how to fix this please?    thanks again!

Comment: @LeoSimon: I've updated my answer. Needed `\noexpand\setcounter`.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed!